# count array length in c by pointer, the answer is wrong

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[3] = {1,2,3};

void cal(int* item){
    printf("Length(inside) is %lu\n", sizeof(item)/sizeof(item[0]));
}

int main(){
    printf("Length(outside) is %lu\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    cal(a);
}
```

The code above comes out with the result that

```
Length(outside) is 3
Length(inside) is 2
```

However, it is wrong, because both of them should be 3, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer, not what is points to. If you need the length of the array, you need to pass it as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `%zu` fomat specifier to print the result.

Secondly, when passed to a function as argument, array name decays to the pointer to the first element, so the `sizeof(item)` will not work as expected.

Basically what you're doing is `sizeof (int *)/ sizeof (int)` and in your environment, it is likely that a pointer occupies 8 bytes and an `int` takes `4`, so you get this result.

Comment: Words like "decay" don't mean anything to neophytes unless you define them specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the array decays into a pointer when it is passed to a function.

So essentially what you are doing is

```
sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int);
```

---

What you can think is the difference between

```
int a[5];
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); //this works
```

and

```
int a[5];
int* p = a;
sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]);
```

Comment: Why it decays? I think it should not? What's the problem?